# What to do when re.findall does not find the pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_project_name(project_string):
    GG = '%.2f' % (float(re.findall(r"\d+\.?\d*", str(project_string))[0]))
    print (GG)
    return GG
```

Sometimes the entries that this function gets are blank and this gives "index out of range error".

How can I fix it to ignore the entries that are blank then keep going on? Thank you.

Comment: You could check the length of the return value of `re.findall()` before you attempt to access its first element. Alternatively, you could use `try ... except`

Comment: Why are you using `findall` if you only want the first? Use `re.search`

Comment: I am scanning multiple Excel rows to retrieve a number.

Comment: @Allen right, by why are you using `findall` instead of `search` when you *only want the first result*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `try`and `except`.

```
def get_project_name(project_string):
    try:
       GG = '%.2f' % (float(re.findall(r"\d+\.?\d*", str(project_string))[0]))
       print GG
       return GG
    except Exception:
       print "Some error message"
```

Comment: You should explicitely catch an `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same logic to both the "found" and "not found" case, you could also use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next) with a default value (split up a bit to make it clearer):

```
p = r"\d+\.?\d*"
text = str(project_string)
GG = '%.2f' % (float(next(re.findall(p, text), 0.0)))
```

But if you only need the first match, it would actually be better to use `re.finditer` or `re.search`, but those return `Match` objects, not the matched strings directly.

```
m = re.search(p, text)
GG = '%.2f' % (float(m.group()) if m else 0.0)
```